# Is there a way to update the URL in Flow Router without a refresh/redirect?

Tags: meteor, flow-router

Is there a way to update a part of the URL reactively without using `FlowRouter.go()` while using React and `react-layout`?

I want to change the value in the document that is used to get the document from the DB. For example, if I have a route like `~/users/:username` and update the `username` field in the document, I then have to user `FlowRouter.go('profile', {data})` to direct the user to that new URL. The "old" route is gone.

Below is the working version I have, but there are two issues:

1. I have to use `FlowRouter.go()`, which is actually a full page refresh (and going back would be a 404).
2. I still get errors in the console because for a brief moment the reactive data for the component is actually wrong.

Relevant parts of the component are like this:

```
...
mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

getMeteorData() {
  let data = {};

  let users = Meteor.subscribe('user', {this.props.username});

  if (user.ready())
    data.user = user;

  return data;
}
...

updateName(username) {
  Users.update({_id:this.data.user._id}, {$set:{username}}, null, (e,r) => {
      if (!e)
        FlowRouter.go('profile', {username});
    });
},
...
```

The route is like this:

```
FlowRouter.route('/users/:username', {
  name: 'profile',
  action(params) {
    ReactLayout.render(Main, {content: <UserProfile {...params} />});
  }
});
```

The errors I get in the console are:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
```

and

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

Comment: why don't you use an immutable id like `_id` to define the route instead of the username? that'd make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Because this is easier for users to share with other people. This is the same reason your Twitter URL ends in your username, not your ID in Twitter's DB.

Comment: but you don't change your twitter username... and URL are easily cut and pasted. if you need to get persistence then you should save the history of usernames to look it up in the router. but then you may end up with conflicts if a username is reused later.

Comment: Not to get off-topic, but you can change your username on Twitter, it's just that the URL is https://twitter.com/settings/account and that avoids this issue. Using an immutable is an easier solution, but still hoping I can accomplish the original idea.